# Convert COVID data into data points using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to create a script that takes Covid-19 data in a CSV file format and put it into a ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy. Here is my code. However, I am getting an error saying the parameters are not valid. It says that my in table name does not exist even though it does. What am I doing wrong?

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\butle\Downloads\final project"
#gives the location of the csv file
csv_file = r'C:\Users\butle\Downloads\County-Case-Counts.csv'
    
inTable = "County-Case-Counts.csv"
outLocation = r'C:\Users\butle\Downloads\final project\covid-19data.gdb'
    
    
arcpy.AddField_management('Conty-Case-Counts.csv','counties',field_is_nullable="NULLABLE")
    
    
expression = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters("County of Residence") + " = 'covidata' "
    
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("County-Case-Counts.csv", r'C:\Users\butle\Downloads\final project\covid-19data.gdb','covid-19data')
    
inFeatures = "covid-19data"
joinTable = "County of Residence"
joinField = "US_Counties"
expression = "County-Case-Counts.US_Counties = 1"
outFeature = "countyjoin"
    
county_joined_table = arcpy.Addjoin_management(inFeatures, joinField, joinTable, joinField)
    
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(county_joined_table, "NEW_SECTION",expression)
    
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(county_joined_table, outFeature)
    
arcpy.CalcuateField_management("County-Case_Counts.csv", "countyjoin")
```

Comment: MakeXYEventlayer - Join - Copy features

Answer (score 1):

Check your `inTable` variable. "County-Case-Counts.csv"

That's the name of your file. Just double check that the name of the table here. The '.csv' part to me doesn't look right, usually tables are not suffixed by the filename.

e.g.: If you imported a shapefile, the table name would be 'data'... not 'data.shp'

Or possibly just this line is missing a `u` in the word County (you typed `Conty`)

```
arcpy.AddField_management('Conty-Case-Counts.csv', 'counties', field_is_nullable="NULLABLE")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't converted your CSV to a table called "County-Case-Counts.csv" prior to running this script, you need to call TableToTable_conversion first, with a full path to the csv (which you have defined as "csv_file").
You can then call AddField_management on the GDB class you have created.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\butle\Downloads\final project"
#gives the location of the csv file
csv_file = r'C:\Users\butle\Downloads\County-Case-Counts.csv'
    
inTable = "County-Case-Counts.csv"
outLocation = r'C:\Users\butle\Downloads\final project\covid-19data.gdb'
    
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(csv_file, outLocation, 'covid_19data')
    
arcpy.AddField_management('covid_19data','counties',field_is_nullable="NULLABLE")
 
...
```

Comment: the table name 'covid-19data' contains an invalid character. The '-' will cause the table to table conversion tool to throw an error (000354) when saving out to a file geodatabase.

Comment: True, nice catch.